# Is it allowed to put G-d's most revered name in a wooden bracelet?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, jewelry

Is it allowed for someone to put some sort of wooden bracelet engraved in it "lamed yud heh vav heh" like saying that this person belongs to G-d only and to remind this person that he is G-d's and to always remember his master ?

Comment: They might not be able to wear it into the bathroom...

Comment: I thought we've had this question already.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's for sure since anything related to G-d must not enter the toilet..

Comment: @msh210 can you give me the link please ?

Comment: Dunno. That's why I didn't link to it (or close this as a duplicate). I may well be mistaken.

Comment: If you're going to make one that says  la'hadshem, also make one that says "la'azazel" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wouldn't be sure where the person wearing the bracelet might end up going, it would be better to avoid such a practice. There are places where a Jew should not bring written names, like into a bathroom for example.

A better practice would be to write a common abbreviation that many people write in any holy book they own. Namely, לה״ הו״מ. This means that the earth and all that fills it belong to G-d. There a no names involved but it communicates the sentiment you are trying to convey.